# Does having mpsc channels require some additional "hidden" overhead in rust?

Tags: rust, concurrency, channel

When I create a rust mpsc channel, is the mpsc::Receiver datatype responsible for all of the overhead of the channel, or is it a facade for some larger more complex data?

The reason I am asking this question is to find out if I can have a bunch of "cheap" and relatively idle channels sitting around waiting for their occasional use, or will they each require a bunch of overhead.

Sorry if this question is a bit of a mess.

Comment: All the code is available, so you can just read the source, the official documentation actually has `source` links which link to a code viewer with colorisation (do remember to click the top-left arrow to open the sidebar if it's not open yet, that makes it easier to navigate). The standard library code is usually quite easy to follow, aside from a few core types like numbers which are pretty much entirely macro-ed to deduplicate.

Comment: Channels do not add any computing overhead by just existing.

Comment: Ok thank you Ivan and Masklinn.